# How to upload file field (html form) to database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, thymeleaf

I have html form (Thymeleaf) that contains field for uploading file.

[image: html form]

In model object, field `file` is set as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "services")
public class Service {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "service_id")
  private Long serviceId;

  @Size(min = 5, message = "Please enter 5 symbols or more")
  @NotBlank(message = "This field is mandatory")
  private String event;

  @NotNull(message = "This field is mandatory")
  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
  private LocalDate created;

  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
  private LocalDate modified;

  private BigDecimal price;

  @Lob
  private byte[] file;
  ...
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/services")
  public String addEvent(
      @Valid @ModelAttribute("service") Service service,
      BindingResult bindingResult,
      Model model
  ) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
      return "service-add-event";
    } else {
      serviceRepository.save(service);
    }
    List<Service> services = serviceRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("services", services);
    return "redirect:/services";
    }
  }
```

View:

```
  <form action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/services}" th:object="${service}">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="event">Event *</label>
      <input th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('event')} ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'" 
id="event" th:field="*{event}" type="text">
      <div class="invalid-feedback" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('event')}" th:errors="*{event}">Name Error</div>
    </div>

    ...

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="maintenanceFile">Maintenance File</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="maintenanceFile" th:field="*{file}" type="file">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
```

After saving to database (H2 embedded), I see that **only filename** is saved to field file (for example `Testfile.txt`), not the whole file. Why?

How to save the whole file to database?

Comment: Did you forget to put [enctype="multipart/form-data"](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) into `form` tag?

Comment: @SlavaIvanov Yes, I didn't put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` at `form` tag, because it caused spring validation error `Cannot convert MutipartFile to required type byte[] for property value`

Comment: You have to have `enctype` in the HTML form set to the proper value in order to get the file content. You will get it as `MultipartFile` and need to convert this object to byte array yourself. For example one of the solutions may be as simple as [Spring MVC failed to convert property value in file upload form](https://mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-failed-to-convert-property-value-in-file-upload-form/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got some advises from other developers and solved this issue.

1. First, need to put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` into `form` tag.
2. Second, need to divide form objects into 2 parts. Service instance with simple fields (field `file` would be 'null'). And multipart input tag. This is needed, because multipart is a stream (not a field), and should be handled in Controller separately.
3. Then, in Controller we get byte array from multipart, set this bytes to Service object field, and save the instance to Repository.

**Code example:**

View:

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:object="${service}" 
th:action="@{/services}">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="event">Event *</label>
      <input th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('event')} ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'"
             id="event" th:field="*{event}" type="text">
      <div class="invalid-feedback" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('event')}" th:errors="*{event}">
        Name Error
      </div>

    (...)

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="maintenanceFile">Maintenance File</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="maintenanceFile" name="maintenanceFile" type="file">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button"
       th:href="@{/services}">Cancel</a>
  </form>
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/services", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
  public String addEvent(
      @Valid @ModelAttribute("service") Service service,
      BindingResult bindingResult,
      @RequestParam("maintenanceFile") MultipartFile maintenanceFile,
      Model model
  ) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
      return "service-add-event";
    } else {
      if (!maintenanceFile.isEmpty()) {
        try {
          byte[] fileBytes = maintenanceFile.getBytes();
          service.setFile(fileBytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      serviceRepository.save(service);
      List<Service> services = serviceRepository.findAll();
      model.addAttribute("services", services);
      return "redirect:/services";
    }
  }
```